# Inserting an entry in hash at certain position

Tags: ruby, hash

Given a hash:

```
{"set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]}
```

how can I add a new key-value pair after the set_filter entry? The expected output should be something like this:

```
{
  "set_filter" => ["0"],
  "test3" => ["=test3"],
  "test1" => ["=test1"],
  "test2" => ["=test2"]
}
```

I want to insert a new key-value pair at a certain position in a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

- extract the keys from the hash and find the index of the given key
- add one to the index if the given pair is to be inserted after, rather than before, the given key
- convert the hash to an array
- insert the pair in the array before the computed index (which is after the last pair if the index equals the size of the array)
- convert the resulting array back to a hash

```
def insert_pair(h, key, pair, proximity=:before)
  h.to_a.insert(h.keys.index(key) + (proximity==:after ? 1 : 0), pair.first).to_h
end

h = {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]}
pair = {"test3"=>["=test3"]}

insert_pair(h, "set_filter", pair, :after)
  #=> {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test3"=>["=test3"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]} 
insert_pair(h, "set_filter", pair)
  #=> {"test3"=>["=test3"], "set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]} 
insert_pair(h, "test2",      pair, :after)
  #=> {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"], "test3"=>["=test3"]}
```

I've made `:before` the default to be consistent with [Array#insert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-insert).

Here's an alternative approach that does not convert the hash to an array, modify the array and then convert it back to a hash. Rather, it splits the existing hash into two hashes, slips a single-key hash between them and then merges all three into a single hash.

```
def insert_pair(h, key, pair, proximity=:before)
  keys = h.keys
  before_keys =
  case proximity
  when :before
    key==keys.first ? [[], keys] : keys.slice_before { |k| k == key }
  when :after
    keys.slice_after { |k| k == key }
  end.first
  h.select { |k,_| before_keys.include? k }.
    update(pair).
    update(h.reject { |k,_| before_keys.include? k }) 
end

insert_pair(h, "set_filter", pair, :after)
  #=> {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test3"=>["=test3"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]} 
insert_pair(h, "set_filter", pair)
  #=> {"test3"=>["=test3"], "set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]} 
insert_pair(h, "test2",      pair, :after)
  #=> {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"], "test3"=>["=test3"]}
```

Comment: Note this is actually less efficient than removing and re-adding elements: http://ideone.com/HUKp7z

Comment: @Yam, that's a useful finding. I just noticed that my answer is similar to your (earlier) answer.

Comment: Granted, though, in cases where performance is not a huge concern (which is arguably most Ruby apps), this is definitely the more elegant way to go by.

Answer (score 6):

The only order hashes provide is order of insertion, and that only affects iteration. So you can't really *add after* a specific element, unless you're willing to remove all those following it, insert, and then insert all those back again.

Instead, you might want to use an array of pairs, like this:

```
A = [["set_filter", "0"], ...]
```

and then use `Array#insert`, like this

```
A.insert(2, ["test3", "=test3"])
```

When order matters, use the array.
When you need a hash interface, you can do

```
A.to_h # yields { 'set_filter' => '0', ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

A minor improvement to @cary's answer (I would comment on it directly, but I don't have enough reputation).

If you wish to insert multiple hash keys at once (a `pair` with multiple keys), you can use this modification of @cary's variant one:

```rb
def insert_pair(h, key, pair, proximity=:before)
  h.to_a.insert(h.keys.index(key) + (proximity==:after ? 1 : 0), *pair.to_a).to_h
end

h = {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]}

#insert pair with one hash key
pair = {"test3"=>["=test3"]}
insert_pair(h, "set_filter", pair, :after)
  #=> {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test3"=>["=test3"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]} 

#insert pair with >1 hash keys
pair = {"test3"=>["=test3"], "test4" => ["=test4"], "test5" => ["=test5"]}
insert_pair(h, "set_filter", pair, :after)
  #=> {"set_filter"=>["0"], "test3"=>["=test3"], "test4" => ["=test4"], "test5 => ["=test5"], "test1"=>["=test1"], "test2"=>["=test2"]}
```

**Note:** that `pair` can be one or more hash keys, so this doesn't break the original use case, merely extends it.